# Mongo / Mongoose query works in Mongo shell but not in Node (on EC2 Ubuntu image)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongoose

I'm having a hard time determining why this query works in the Mongo shell but not when I try to hit the server endpoint from the browser.

Shell command:

```
db.playlists.find({keywords: {"$in" : ["featured"]}}).limit(5)
```

Server code:

```
app.get('/getFeaturedPlaylists', (req, res) => { 
  let query = {
    keywords: { "$in" : ["featured"]}
  }
  database.Playlist.find({query}).limit(5).exec(function(err, data) {                 
    err ? console.log(err) : res.send({body: JSON.stringify(data)});
  })
})
```

Expected result is an array of playlist objects:

```
{"body": "[{\"songList\":[{\"songId\":522,\"bpm\":45},{\"songId\":310,\"bpm\":45},{\"songId\":199,\"bpm\":90},{\"songId\":170,\"bpm\":150},{\"songId\":17,\"bpm\":150},{\"songId\":722,\"bpm\":45},{\"songId\":767,\"bpm\":90},{\"songId\":754,\"bpm\":120},{\"songId\":844,\"bpm\":150},{\"songId\":422,\"bpm\":120},{\"songId\":638,\"bpm\":90},{\"songId\":243,\"bpm\":150},{\"songId\":524,\"bpm\":90},{\"songId\":575,\"bpm\":120},{\"songId\":143,\"bpm\":120}],\"shuffledQueue\":[],\"keywords\":[\"bluegrass\",\"featured\"],\"_id\":\"5a76188fde76d97bda5e342e\",\"playlistId\":2,\"playlistName\":\"Playlist2\"},{\"songList\":[{\"songId\":401,\"bpm\":45},{\"songId\":536,\"bpm\":150},{\"songId\":982,\"bpm\":60},{\"songId\":812,\"bpm\":60},{\"songId\":466,\"bpm\":150}],\"shuffledQueue\":[],\"keywords\":[\"featured\",\"bluegrass\"],\"_id\":\"5a76188fde76d97bda5e3432\",\"playlistId\":6,\"playlistName\":\"Playlist6\"},{\"songList\":[{\"songId\":248,\"bpm\":120},{\"songId\":84,\"bpm\":45},{\"songId\":53,\"bpm\":60},{\"songId\":749,\"bpm\":45},{\"songId\":811,\"bpm\":120}],\"shuffledQueue\":[],\"keywords\":[\"featured\",\"hip-hop\"],\"_id\":\"5a76188fde76d97bda5e3433\",\"playlistId\":7,\"playlistName\":\"Playlist7\"},{\"songList\":[{\"songId\":894,\"bpm\":150},{\"songId\":190,\"bpm\":60},{\"songId\":235,\"bpm\":60},{\"songId\":632,\"bpm\":60},{\"songId\":970,\"bpm\":60},{\"songId\":475,\"bpm\":90},{\"songId\":304,\"bpm\":60},{\"songId\":816,\"bpm\":120},{\"songId\":613,\"bpm\":150},{\"songId\":310,\"bpm\":45},{\"songId\":599,\"bpm\":45},{\"songId\":91,\"bpm\":90},{\"songId\":650,\"bpm\":120},{\"songId\":219,\"bpm\":45},{\"songId\":290,\"bpm\":90}],\"shuffledQueue\":[],\"keywords\":[\"hip-hop\",\"featured\"],\"_id\":\"5a76188fde76d97bda5e3436\",\"playlistId\":10,\"playlistName\":\"Playlist10\"},{\"songList\":[{\"songId\":778,\"bpm\":60},{\"songId\":652,\"bpm\":60},{\"songId\":792,\"bpm\":90},{\"songId\":353,\"bpm\":120},{\"songId\":528,\"bpm\":60},{\"songId\":887,\"bpm\":120},{\"songId\":287,\"bpm\":90},{\"songId\":926,\"bpm\":120},{\"songId\":671,\"bpm\":90}],\"shuffledQueue\":[],\"keywords\":[\"featured\",\"reggae\"],\"_id\":\"5a76188fde76d97bda5e3437\",\"playlistId\":11,\"playlistName\":\"Playlist11\"}]"}
```

Actual result is an empty array:

```
{"body":"[]"}
```

Even more peculiar, this issue only arose when I moved the server and database to EC2 instances. Using the exact same code and data set on my local machine, it responds as I expect it to (via Postman or Chrome -- this is how I got the "expected response" snippet above). Additionally, all of the other server endpoints pointing at this database work, but they're only looking for individual playlists.

Any insights into this would be greatly appreciated, and of course I'm happy to provide any more details as needed.

Thanks!

Comment: u try to send something like this: `db.Playlist.find({{keywords: {$in: ['...']}}})` , but need: `db.Playlist.find({keywords: {$in: ['...']}})`, for doing that u need remove `{}`, and it will looks like: `database.Playlist.find(query).limit(5). ...` your query - is already object, you don't need **{}** around query

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the issue,

```
 database.Playlist.find({query})
```

You're not passing the query object but rather an empty object `{ }` with `{query}`.

Do this instead,

```
 database.Playlist.find(query)
```

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! Any insight as to why the .find({query}) syntax would work on my local machine but not on the EC2 instance?